# How can I display images instead of names(text) in my Opencart subcategories?

Tags: php, smarty, opencart, categories

So a normal subcategory on Opencart looks like this, example:
Category: Apple
Subcategories: iPhone 3, iPhone 4, iPhone 5

Now, those subcategories are all in text, but I want to display images of them on the subcategories page (which is www.site.com/Apple)

For the category.php file, which is in catelog/controller/module/category.php
I added the following code:

```
$this->load->model('tool/image');
$image = empty($category['image']) ? 'no_image.jpg' : $category['image'];
$thumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize($image, 100, 100);
```

And then for the subcategory array, which normally looks like this:

```
$children_data[] = array(               
 'category_id' => $child['category_id'],                    
 'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),                         
 'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
);
```

I added the following object in:

```
'thumb'       => $thumb,
```

So then as last, in my view file which is category.tpl, located at: view/theme/mytheme/template/product/category.tpl there is this line:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $categories[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $categories[$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
```

And I changed the ['name'] to ['thumb'] (and around the php quotes I added html  tags. 
But after all this. I am still stuck with this error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: image in /home/web/catalog/view/theme/theme/template/product/category.tpl on line 36

I've been stuck with this for hours now, your help is appreciated!

Comment: Your code seems ok, but the error tells you there is a variable "$image" that is not specified, form your code above there should be no such variable so this is a bit awkward, please confirm that there are no vqmod scripts messing up things.

Comment: I think I am working in the wrong folders, I just found out. Because the stuff in the controller for the category is for the real category. But I do not want to display images for the category, just for the subcategories. And those are I think in the product folder, instead of the module folder.

Comment: yeap categories that appear as pages have all the needed data in category.tpl in product folder, category.tpl in module folder is only used for the module that yo need to first activate as an extension and so on.

Comment: On Opencart, if you have a category called lets say Apple. Now in that category the subcategories are: iPhone 3, iPhone 4. I only want to change the text of THAT subcategory, not the original category which is Apple. So in which folders should I work in the controller? I think it's the product folder, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

**Find Code** (in category.php)

```
$this->data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
                );
```

**Replace Code**

```
$image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_category_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_category_height'));
            $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url), 'thumb' => $image
            );
```

& also,

**Add code** (in category.tpl)

```
<div class="category-list">
         <ul class="list-item">
         <?php $counter = 0; foreach ($categories as $category) {?>  
                <li>
                    <?php if ($category['thumb']) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $category['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" /></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><img src="image/no_image.jpg" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" /></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
        <?php $counter++; } ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

& then check it.

Comment: I am not sure where to add the the tpl stuff, because in the controller/product/category.tpl, it's different

Comment: You can find category.tpl file Here: Go to catalog > view > theme > default(your theme) > template > product > category.tpl